# Error al publicar: Para habilitar la opción en el cuadro de diálogo Requisitos previos debe descargar el archivo

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy publicando mi proyecto que desarrolle en C# en forma de escritorio. Lo que pasa que al publicarlo me manda el siguiente error:

> Para habilitar la opción "Descargar los requisitos previos desde la misma ubicación que mi aplicación" en el cuadro de diálogo Requisitos previos, debe descargar el archivo 'DotNetFX461\NDP461-x86-x64-AllOS-ESN.exe' para el elemento 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 (x86 y x64)' al equipo local. Para obtener más información, vea http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616018.

Como se ve en la siguiente captura de pantalla:

[image: captura de pantalla del error]

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? ¿O dónde debo ingresar para descargar ese archivo?

Comment: lo que veo parece ser un error de net framework.. tienes instalado net 4.6.1?? no se mucho pero he programado wpf y las he publicado sin problemas pues le dije al instalador de vs2017 que me instalara todos las versiones de net Framework creo que es eso.

Comment: Y bajaste esos archivos? el error es claro, tenes que tener esos archivos en tu pc tambien para que arme el instalador

Comment: El enlace del error va a una página que tiene [otro enlace a la página](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers) donde puedes descargar el archivo (en la primera nota). ¿Has encontrado algún problema al instalarlo?

Comment: Hola luchas Gracias por su ayuda, resolví mi problema utilizando **Visual Studio Installer**. Gracias.